# Hovering over one div triggers another div

Tags: html, css

How would I go about hovering over an image that then blurs the background image behind it within css? The way I have it set up now is the background image blurs upon hover.
Here's my **css:**

```
.blur img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.blur img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
.wrapper{
    width:900x;
    height: 100px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 2400px;
    z-index: 50;
}
.logo{
    postion: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 2420px;
    z-index: 50;
    left: 400px;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="blur"><img src="/homepic1.jpg"></div>//This is the image I want blurred 

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 pagination-centered">
            <img src="/transparanetsnu.png">//How do I hover over any of these images to trigger a blur on "homepic1.jpg"
        </div>
        <div class="span4 offset3">
            <div class="box2"><img src="/greek_logo.gif"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="/UM-Main-Logo-Maroon.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: You can't refer to previous elements with CSS, only after elements that's how a Cascade Style Sheet works.

Comment: Your best bet is to use Javascript for this. While it might be _possible_ to do this with just CSS, it's definitely not going to be simple and/or compatible with all browsers... And that's only if it is possible. Meanwhile, just a few lines of JS will get you exactly what you need.

Comment: Is that the correct HTML? It looks pretty wonky... Two closing `</div>` tags for the first opening `<div>` tag and not enough closing `</div>` tags... My main questions is regarding the nesting of the `div.blur` element, is it nested within `div.wrapper` by chance?

Comment: sorry. yes it does look wonky my apologies. I cut out a portion of the  html code for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use JQuery. All images and add a class like 'blur' to them everytime user hover over one image, but you should remove the class from the one you don't want.

```
$('.img1').mouseover(function(){
    $('img').addClass('blur');
    $('.img1').removeClass('blur');
});
```

Add the effect using css or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery for that purpose.
First of all dowload jQuery from: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
Then.

```
$('.yourImage').mouseover(function(){ //'.yourImage' are the last three images in your case.
    $('.homepic1').addClass('blur'); //'.homepic1' is the class of first image in your case
});
```

.addClass('blur') , Will add the class 'blur' from your CSS to that '.homepic1' element, As soon as your mouse hovers over ANY of the three images.